# Rails model reference two db colums to one table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to reference two columns in one model to the other model. I was trying like this:

```
rails g model match team:references team:references tourtament:references winner:integer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give you columns separate names, for example:

```
rails g model match left_team:references right_team:references
```

In your Match model you can do:

```
belongs_to :left_team, class_name: 'Team'
belongs_to :right_team, class_name: 'Team'
```